# How to set start time for video(HLS) segment

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, libavcodec, libav, libavformat

I`m using FFmpeg [muxing.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/muxing.c) example

My generated .ts files have start time: 0.000000
if I run

```
 av_dump_format(oc, 0, filename, 1);
```

How to set this value for output conteiner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found out start time is deduced from pts of first frame of the stream

So in case of muxing.c example

```
ost->frame->pts = <your offset> + ost->next_pts++
```